# Networking not working on Packer created Ubuntu VirtualBox VM

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, packer

I'm trying to build a VirtualBox Ubuntu VM using Packer.

My image was successfully created and I configured it to use my Wi-Fi (Mac OS X AirPort) interface for bridged networking. However, after booting up the VM it only has the loopback interface set up.

**Edit:** here are more details on what's causing the problem:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=44281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this as a provisioning script:

https://github.com/chef/bento/blob/master/packer/scripts/ubuntu/networking.sh

See here for some more details: https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/866